# I need javac 1.6.0_20 in Ubuntu 20, how can I install that

Tags: java

the apt repository doesn't that this version, how to accomplish this? I have tried

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

But this version seems not there

Comment: Public updates for Java 6 ended in 2013, that's 8 years ago. No "normal" software distribution will include a built-in way to install it. Find some places that does a dedicated packaging for current Linux systems or install a manual download.

Answer (score 1):

Java 6 is EOF, that's why you have to install by hand.
You can get unsupported versions from the oracle archive: https://www.oracle.com/de/java/technologies/javase-java-archive-javase6-downloads.html

Comment: You mean EOL: end of life.